# Datasets about ships trips in the Seine river

Tags: dataset, ais

Marinetraffic.com offers so much data about ships tracks history, state, statistics. I am intereseted in collecting similar data to develop an ETA prediction module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect AIS data yourself, you need:

- a receiver such as [this one](https://comarsystems.com/product/network-ais-receiver-for-coastal-monitoring-applications/)
- an AIS antenna

You will then program your receiver to forward the traffic to a given IP by TCP, and then use a library such as [libAIS](https://github.com/schwehr/libais/) to decode those messages.

Answer (score 0):

The Danish Maritime Authority [publishes](https://www.dma.dk/SikkerhedTilSoes/Sejladsinformation/AIS/Sider/default.aspx) historical AIS data from Danish waters. Unfortunately not in NMEA format - but in a parsed CSV format. But the data are still based on AIS.

If that is ok, you can grab data here: ftp://ftp.ais.dk/ais_data/